# nashorn - How to avoid "ReferenceError: "a" is not defined"

Tags: nashorn

The below code throws ReferenceError: "a" is not defined.
Is it possible to avoid it and treat the variable as null?

```
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        Map<String, String> s = new HashMap<String, String>();
//        s.put("a", "a");
        Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
        bindings.putAll(s);
        Object res = engine.eval("!a", bindings);
        System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: Not familiar with Nashorn, but I doubt that, since that would be incompatible with the ECMAScript standard. If you want it to be `null`, then you have to declare it as such (one way or the other). Maybe Nashorn has a way to predefine bindings of the global environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any variable by the name "a" defined in your scope chain, then ReferenceError should be thrown as per the ECMAScript specification. If you uncomment this line:

```
//        s.put("a", "a");
```

line then "a" is defined and therefore no ReferenceError.

You can check if a variable is defined or not using the "typeof" operator. "typeof a == 'undefined'" will evaluate to false for undefined variable "a". You won't get ReferenceError for undefined variables. Again this is standard compliant behavior.